# Is this a bad regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

In a recent talk to junior JavaScript developers I mentioned the following technique for cutting down laborious if/else blocks where the OR operand is used:

```
if (/^(cat|dog|horse)$/.test(animal)) { ... }
```

rather than

```
if (animal == 'cat' || animal == 'dog' || animal == 'horse') { ... }
```

I've never had a problem with this but one person suggested it was a bad design pattern, without elaborating on why.

Comment: I think the regex is quite clear in this case, not like the regex that are suggested in most of the questions in regex tag on SO.

Comment: I don't know whether or not JS is against this, but in other languages I would create a collection inline and see if the value is in there.

Comment: I don't think I'd go so far as to call this "a design pattern".

Comment: @Utkanos: Call it an "idiom" or an "approach". It's just a way to do string matching and doesn't warrant a big term like "pattern".

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me to be "trying to be too clever" and, in doing so, you've introduced several new potential points of failures (in the regex syntax), and made the code less expressive/idiomatic. You'd also struggle if your operands were to go from being `'cat'` to being dynamic or variable in some way.

Typically, in doing things like this, I only go so far as introducing an array:

```
if (['cat', 'dog', 'horse'].indexOf(animal) != -1) { ... }
```

Honestly, though, this is all laughably subjective so there is no "right" answer I can give you.

Usually at this point I'd introduce performance concerns, but you may actually have a faster solution here due to the need to scan the input only once. That would depend upon how quickly the regex itself can be parsed.

Comment: Yes, it's one of those questions on SO where, despite being opinion-based, it's probably a good question. I think SO is yet to find the right balance on opinion-based questions; it's technically not what they want, yet there's loads and loads of them on here, with many upvotes, too.

Comment: @Utkanos: That's why I answered it, rather than closing it.

Comment: btw, the "they have many upvotes" argument is tired and lacking in merit: the masses are ignorant.

Comment: "Usually at this point I'd introduce performance concerns" Unless I screwed up (wouldn't surprise me) this is almost as "slow" as the regex solution http://jsperf.com/is-this-a-bad-design-pattern. But readability FTW!

Comment: Easy, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, no need to sound so harsh and arrogant.

Comment: @Utkanos: There's nothing "arrogant" about it (drop the personal attacks): in any given system populated by large numbers of people, the vocal majority don't take into consideration the reasons for the rules to be in place in the first place. It's provable.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression way is no doubt I would prefer in this case rather thank having long list of comparisons. Performance wise also I think regex won't be drastically inferior to multiple comparisons (imagine a case of 30-40 comparison for your animal).

Regex also gives you other benefits like checking ignore case match or comparison with word boundary (for these case when input is part of some text) whereas this will require an additional code otherwise for string comparison.

Comment: You've pretty backed up my thoughts on why I like this pattern. Thanks.

Comment: For performance reference a crappy benchmark http://jsperf.com/is-this-a-bad-design-pattern. +1 to this answer though

Comment: @PeeHaa: I think you can make an answer out of your benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a regex is more expensive than doing a few string comparisons, but if it makes the code clearer and performance isn't affected (via profiling of course!), then i think it's fine.

Comment: Thanks. Re: expensive, I would have thought this was beyond negligible for comparisons of this small nature, but I take the point.

Answer (score 1):

This is opinion based, but some points to raise are:

Code should be readable, not nessesarly short.

Regex is more error prone, for example: if one forgot `$` this will match `horses`

Without docs someone reading code refactoring code might not be sore it's purpose:

- Should it differentiate animals? `^cat|dog|horse$`
- Should it differentiate animals count? `^cat|dog|horse`

Adding more variants might be problematic, ie:

```
if (animal == 'cat' || animal == 'dog' || animal == someUserInputtedAnimal)
```

**Solution:**

For many if statements use switch or "true" switch:

```
switch (animal)
{
    case 'cat':
        break;
    case 'dog':
        break;
    case 'horse':
        break;
}

switch (true)
{
    case animal == 'cat':
        break;
    case animal == 'dog':
        break;
    case animal == 'horse':
        break;
    case someRandomAnimal == ressurected:

        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I'm aware of switch statements but the point was, to try to limit laborious comparisons to shorter code. The switch is not shorter.

Comment: The point here is more readable code, not shorter. Long if is not readable in my opinion.

Comment: For OPs use case I would very much use a regex pattern instead of a long list of a switch statement

Comment: ew @ "true switch"; that's even worse!

Comment: @PeterM It really, really, really isn't.